# Seeing what Threshold value a layer was previously set to

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-editing

Hi I am trying to play around with a multilayer stencil I previously generated. In order to do so I would like to see what threshold value each layer was originally set to. Is there a way to go back and see what value was chosen for each layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved and quit the document, then the history will be lost forever, and you can't go back.

If you didn't quit the document, then the history states should still be available.  You could duplicate the document, then undo until you get back to that point. However the history states aren't always available all the way back to every point. You can often only go back so far.

In Photoshop CC, in the Preferences, you can also switch on the History Log to save history states to metadata or to a text file. Obviously you can't apply this retrospectively.